# MKStorekit consumable items configuring MKStoreKitConfigs.plist iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I am using MKSorekit for inapp purcase.
I need two consumables in my app. I have tried but some problem.
I don't know how to configure the MKStoreKitConfigs.plist.
I have entered all items in the consumables dictionary an strings, but I found that that is not correct. Each item should be  dict,
Can anyone tell how to set values and keys for that dicts
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add a Dictionary with two keys: `Count` and `Name`. That's all you need

`Name` is the name of your product and `Count` is a virtual count associated with it.

Comment: thank you I've already found that. Any way thank you for your reply